# know count of chars in TJ operand , know where you have to split (delimiter characters or white space characters contains) TJ line in pdf?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I read "7.2 Lexical conventions"  from adobe 1.7 documentation. Still didn't clear that how count number of chars in a Tj Operand. I am confused when applying this like code in PDFBox.

page -1

[image]

Related content stream

[image]

Page -2

[image]
Related content stream

[image]

In above use cases I don't know which kind of char sets they used. I dont know how to count letters by seeing them. And don't know by using PDFBox in page2 the highlighted line till "In f" I need to locate in content stream.

When I parsed using PDFBox the highlighted TJ line in page2 is giving like

[image]

[image]

If you see in 2nd index the number of bytes were 6 but in content stream able to see only 4 like below.

[image]

What is the correct way of counting and locating positions. I want to split after 'n' char in second page . How to do that?

I want to split code at index 4.

```
private static List<Object> splitTJ(inst knum, ind TJ_ind, COSArray tj_array)
{
splitedstr = new COSString( ((COSString)tj_array.get(TJ_ind)).getString().substring(0, knum));
splitedstr2 = new COSString(((COSString)tj_array.get(TJ_ind)).getString().substring(knum, ((COSString)tj_array.get(TJ_ind)).getString().length()));
// This below method  will take care of creating new positioning operator along with Tj or TJ.
CreateNewTj(splitedstr);
CreateNewTj(splitedstr2);
}
```

In above code based on knum index if I splited string bytes its messing up everything because of wrong place split. How can I split preoperly at 4th index?

Answer (score 0):

Where you are *able to see only 4* bytes,

[image]

I see 6 bytes:

1. `\000`
2. `Q`
3. `\000`
4. `\003`
5. `\002`
6. `4`

This matches what you see in your debugger.

To know how many glyphs this represents, you need to know the encoding of the font currently selected when that **TJ** is executed. In regard to

> What is the correct way of counting and locating positions. I want to split after 'n' char in second page . How to do that?

you, therefore, have to inspect that pdf font object and determine its encoding.

Comment: (\0003\226) byte code numbers for these are 3, -106. This byte string represents 'I' only(Respectively '000Q' mens 'n' , '000\003' means ' ' , '002' means 'f' and '4' means small 'i' ). How it could possible. The above given answer can I apply all the different Tj, TJ?

Comment: And at the same time I debugged the font object in PDFStreamEngine.java class method 'showText'. It represents  how count is happening. But still there is no clue for where I have to split and how?

Comment: *'002' means 'f' and '4' means small 'i'* - while theoretically that is possible, i doubt it is the case in your document. More likely the two bytes `\0024` represent the `ﬁ` ligature. *How it could possible.* - as said above, i doubt it is the case. Nonetheless, it would be possible to create such an encoding in pdfs.

Comment: *"The above given answer can I apply all the different Tj, TJ?"* - Well, the answer mainly tells you to count bytes correctly and to interpret the meaning of the byte string parameters of **Tj** and **TJ** instructions according to the encoding of the appropriate PDF font object. So yes, this applies generally.

Comment: *"And at the same time I debugged the font object in PDFStreamEngine.java class method 'showText'. It represents how count is happening. But still there is no clue for where I have to split and how?"* - If you want to *understand* how to count glyphs, you should start at PDF source level; it may help to analyze how some PDF library implements that, but you mainly should use the specification here.

Comment: Furthermore, you should keep in mind that a glyph represented by a single code may print as multiple characters, e.g. in case of ligatures like `ﬁ`. And also the other way around, e.g. an umlaut like `ä` might be drawn using two glyphs, one for the `a` and one for dots above. Thus, don't expect to be able to simply count what you perceive as individual letters.

Comment: Added some code snippet can you give some sample code for above question?

Comment: @fascinatingcoder You completely ignore the font in question. you have to use the font encoding to determine index by index how many bytes are used for the character code at that index and advance by that. As you have already have experience debugging PDFBox in this regard, you should have a look at `org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.showText(byte[])` for an example of that. And of course at the specification, e.g. section 9.7.6.2 and 9.7.6.3 of ISO 32000-1.